# How to find the largest sum over a given consecutive period, from a given date range.

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am looking for a way to search for the largest amount (total from given consecutive workday period)  over a given period (three months of data). 
     For example, A date range of say three months, with some dates containing no fill. First column would contain dates, second column would contain the amount. I need the largest total over that consecutive five day period over that date range. If I just needed the largest number, that would be easy, but I need the largest combined total over some period (example offive days). Thanks for any help! -B

Answer (score 0):

Add a column with `=WEEKNUM(A2)` copied down, create a PivotTable with that as Row Labels and values as Σ Values then apply =MAX to the Sum of Value column in the PT.